# Elasticsearch field breaks into multiple values

Tags: ruby, elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, elastic-stack

I am using the ELK stack for shipping logs.
The problem I'm dealing with is that one of the fields breaks down to multiple values.
To make it clear, for the field product, my values should be:
`Anti Malware`, `New Anti Virus`, `VPN-1 & FireWall-1` and some more.

however, when running :

```
curl --user admin:111111 -XPOST 'localhost:9200/filebeat-2016.07.14/_search?pretty' -d '
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "group_by_product": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "product",
        "script": "_value"
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

The output is:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "group_by_product": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "product"
      }
    }
  }
}'
{
  "took" : 116,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 20,
    "successful" : 20,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 2624573,
    "max_score" : 0.0,
    "hits" : [ ]
  },
  "aggregations" : {
    "group_by_product" : {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count" : 8748,
      "buckets" : [ {
        "key" : "1",
        "doc_count" : 2439769
      }, {
        "key" : "firewall",
        "doc_count" : 2439769
      }, {
        "key" : "vpn",
        "doc_count" : 2439769
      }, {
        "key" : "anti",
        "doc_count" : 166522
      }, {
        "key" : "malware",
        "doc_count" : 87399
      }, {
        "key" : "new",
        "doc_count" : 79123
      }, {
        "key" : "virus",
        "doc_count" : 79123
      }, {
        "key" : "blade",
        "doc_count" : 8249
      }, {
        "key" : "compliance",
        "doc_count" : 8249
      }, {
        "key" : "identity",
        "doc_count" : 5176
      } ]
    }
  }
}
```

So the value `VPN-1 & FireWall-1` breaks into `vpn`, `firewall` and `1`.

I saw that it has something to do with analyzed field, but i cannot define a field as not analyzed bacause the field creation is dynamically.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use dynamic templates. Refer [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/custom-dynamic-mapping.html).

You just need to make sure that fields created dynamically follow a certain pattern or else just use * if you want it to be applicable to all fields. Set your analyzer to keyword. This analyzer passes the string as is.

Comment: Thanks for the response.
I read your reference, and still something is not clear to me.  
In order to apply the dynamic template i need the index to be already exist, and if not, to create it manually, but in my case (and in all ELK cases i believe), the logstash creates the indexes dynamically (in the pattern of: `filebeat-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}`.
So, how can I apply the dynamic template for all indexes?
Thnaks

Comment: You can always get the data to the index of your choice through logstash, there is an option for the index, so you can tell logstash which index to send data to. Further if you dont want to do that, you can always use regex in your mappings like filebeat-%* and mapping would apply to all indexes matching that pattern . Refer to this http://code972.com/blog/2015/02/80-elasticsearch-one-tip-a-day-managing-index-mappings-like-a-pro